# Get Day From Date SwiftUI

Tags: swift, date, swiftui

I want only to get Int day from a date.

```
ScrollView(.horizontal) {
    HStack(spacing: 60) {
        ForEach(steps, id: \.id) { day in
            Text(day.date, style: .date)
                .onTapGesture {
                    selectedDay = day
                }
        }
    }
}
```

With this code, I get the date as `November 5, 2020`, but I only need `5` from all date.

```
struct Step: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let count: Int
    let date: Date
    let wc: Double
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you wanted something like this

```
ForEach(steps, id: \.id) { day in
    Text("\(Calendar.current.dateComponents([.day], from: day.date).day!)")
        .onTapGesture {
            selectedDay = day
        }
}
```